# How are we going to organize tags?

Tags: discussion

While there are still a small number of questions on the site, I think it would be important to get a consensus on tag organization. It becomes trickier to enforce a policy when you already have a thousand existing questions violating the policy.

For example:

- We have an [ebook-readers](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook-readers) tag - this seems largely redundant to me - that's like having a `programming` tag on Stack Overflow.
- We have an [amazon](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag - this is fine if it refers to the Amazon website but redundant on [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-commands-can-be-given-in-the-kindles-search-box), which has nothing to do with [amazon.com](http://amazon.com) and simply uses it to identify the Kindle (which is produced by Amazon).
- Although not terribly important, I feel the [digital-rights-management](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-rights-management) tag should probably point to [drm](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm). There are no questions with the [drm](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm) tag, but I think people recognize the acronym "DRM" more readily than its expanded form.

Thoughts? Comments? Suggestions?

Comment: Agree on the DRM tag suggestion, the abbreviated version is probably more recognizable

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm totally hating that the overall tag management is lumped with (good) discussions about very specific tags. Can you split out the 3 examples in their own questions and link from here?

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion [ebook-readers](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook-readers) is an ambiguous tag. I think we should blacklist it and replace it by [ebook-devices](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook-devices) for the hardware devices and [ebook-viewers](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook-viewers) for e.g. epub reading software on Android or PCs.

It would be nice to have a [hardware](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag reserved for questions that actually deal with hardware questions like "The touch screen of my reader does not respond, can I replace it." (I know that question is crappy, but there may be better ones if somebody actually has the problems).

I agree with [drm](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm). Maybe [amazon](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) should be replaced by [amazon-website](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-website) if used this way.

Comment: I'd prefer `amazon-mechant`. "website" is no longer accurate, you can purchase books from Amazon Android App, or from Kindle app.

Answer (score 3):

The [ebook-readers](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook-readers) tag closely resembles to the [hardware](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag, so technically they could be the same.

There is a lot of tag synonyms to be created here, that's for sure.

Comment: No as per @Tim's answer a ebook reader could be software on any computer

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the amazon tag is appropriate, largely depends on what the definition is. One of the things we certainly have to do is come up with descriptions, that guide first time posters of questions, as well as guide more experienced (re-)taggers in applying the tag to the right question.

It is difficult for me to judge whether an [amazon](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) is appropriate if there is there is no tag definition for that tag.